# Compare 2 consecutive cells in a dataframe for equality

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following problem, I want to detect if 2 or more consecutive values in a column of a dataframe have a value greater than 0.5. For this I have chosen the following approach: I check each cell if the value is less than 0.5 and create an entry in the column "condition". (See table)
Now I have the following problem, how can I detect in a column if 2 consecutive cells have the same value (row 4-5)? Or is it possible to detect the problem also directly in the Data column.
If 2 consecutive cells are False, the dataframe can be discarded.

I would be very grateful for any help!

|  | data | condition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.1 | True |
| 1 | 0.1 | True |
| 2 | 0.25 | True |
| 3 | 0.3 | True |
| 4 | 0.6 | False |
| 5 | 0.7 | False |
| 6 | 0.3 | True |
| 7 | 0.1 | True |
| 6 | 0.9 | False |
| 7 | 0.1 | True |

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is the goal to find 2 consecutive values greater than 0.5?

Comment: Also, if entry 6 were changed to 0.8, would entries 4, 5, and 6 be discarded?

Comment: This is more of a check before the actual calculation starts. As soon as I have two or more values greater than 0.5, the raw data is not suitable for further calculations and can be discarded.

Comment: @MYousefi Yes, i want to detect if 2 or more consecutive values are greater than 0.5. This is used to pre-filter a raw data set. As soon as 2 consecutive values are greater than 0.5, the dataframe can be discarded and no calculations have to be performed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute a boolean series of values greater than 0.5 (i.e True when invalid). Then apply a boolean and (`&`) between this series and its `shift`. Any two consecutive True values will yield True. You can check if `any` is present to decide to discard the dataset:

```
s = df['data'].gt(0.5)
(s&s.shift()).any()
```

Output: `True` -> the dataset is invalid

Comment: Check [your rep history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway?tab=reputation). I modflagged a certain user ("Neither") for downvoting answers for bad reasons, and they got deleted. Now you're freed of 13 pesky downvotes (at least). :) Lol, but I actually lost 10 rep :/

Comment: @richardec this is actually quite sad to some extent (obviously, not the fact that this harassment behavior will now stop). It seems this person has some interesting python knowledge and sometimes even made valuable suggestions (in substance, not form). I just wish they also had the motivation to actually positively contribute to the community.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.diff` method and check that it is equal to zero.

```
df['eq_to_prev'] = df.data.diff().eq(0)
```